# glTexImage2D + byte[]

Tags: c#, opengl, textures

How can I upload pixels from a simple byte array to an OpenGl texture ?

I'm using [glTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) and all I get is a white rectangle instead of a pixelated texture. The 9th parameter (32-bit pointer to the pixel data) is IMO the problem. I tried lots of parameter types there (byte, ref byte, byte[], ref byte[], int & IntPtr + Marshall, out byte, out byte[], byte*). glGetError() always returns GL_NO_ERROR. There must be something I'm doing wrong because it's never some gibberish pixels. It's always white. glGenTextures works correct. The first id has the value 1 like always in OpenGL. And I draw colored lines without any problem. So something is wrong with my texturing. I'm in control of the DllImport. So I can change the parameter types if necessary.

```
GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
int w = 4;
int h = 4;
byte[] bytes = new byte[w * h * 4];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    bytes[i] = (byte)Utils.random(256);
GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
```

```
[DllImport(GL_LIBRARY)] public static extern void glTexImage2D(uint what, int level, int internalFormat, int width, int height, int border, int format,
            int type, byte[] bytes);
```

Comment: What is it that makes you think that it's the image uploading that's the problem?

Comment: Also, how are you marshalling a .NET byte array to a C API function? Your comment "I'm in control of the DllImport" suggests that you're not using OpenTK or some other pre-made OpenGL binding. So what does that code look like?

Comment: What could it be then ? I'm drawing it with GL_QUADS but it always fills it with my current glColor() (white). I'm binding the texture id and enable GL_TEXTURE_2D.

Comment: Right now I'm not marshaling the 9th parameter. Marshaling gave me errors and headache in early trying sessions. If that might be the problem how should I marshal it and how to use the array as parameter ?

Comment: I admit that my knowledge of .NET is somewhat limited, but I'm fairly sure that you can't just pass a .NET `byte[]` to a C API and have it understand it as an `void*` pointer to an array of bytes. You need to pass the data somehow, so show us your code for this function interfacing with the OpenGL API.

Comment: -1: The problem with your question right now is that you haven't told us *nearly* enough to solve it. It could be dozens of things: how you pass the data to OpenGL, how you bind the texture for rendering, what texture coordinates you use, what texture environment variables you use, various combinations of these, etc. We simply need to see more of your code before anyone can do anything more than *guess* at a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

A common mistake is not change the MIN filter, since the default is mipmapped, which makes textures incomplete. Do this:

```
GL.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
GL.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Then draw the texture.

Comment: Ok thx Matias, now I see SOMETHING. Now I can send my byte[] pixels up and do some visible changes. I still have some errors though. Maybe I still have to marshal the bytes somehow ? I posted my dllimport up there.

Answer (score 1):

A texture remaining white despite something has been uploaded is a indicator for either not all mipmap levels being uploaded properly, or filter settings not set correctly.

Of interest is then

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_..., GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_...);
```

With GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR to disable mipmapping. Mipmapping is enabled by default.

The other important thing is to set the structure of the data before uploading, i.e. calling glTexImage. For this you use the function `glPixelStorei` to set the GL_UNPACK_... parameters. You need to set things like alignment, stride, and so on. I refer you to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your P/Invoke declaration is wrong.

The short answer is:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(Library, EntryPoint = "glTexImage2D", ExactSpelling = true)]
internal extern static void glTexImage2D(int target, int level, int internalformat, Int32 width, Int32 height, int border, int format, int type, IntPtr pixels);
```

This P/Invoke declaration is a safe one (not using directly pointers, but *IntPtr*).

The problem is the .NET memory management. Memory blocks are not fixed on a certain memory address: the garbage collector (GC) is free to move memory everywhere (for example, it can move a stack allocated memory in the heap space and viceversa).

Indeed, what you need is to tell to the .NET GC that the memory shall not moved. To do so, you shall use the *fixed* statement or other garbage collector related method.

For example:

```
public static void TexImage2D(int target, int level, int internalformat, Int32 width, Int32 height, int border, int format, int type, object pixels) {
    GCHandle pp_pixels = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try {
        if      (Delegates.pglTexImage2D != null)
            Delegates.pglTexImage2D(target, level, internalformat, width, height, border, format, type, pp_pixels.AddrOfPinnedObject());
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("binding point TexImage2D cannot be found");
     } finally {
         pp_pixels.Free();
     }         
}
```

The object parameter of the *TexImage2D* function is meant to be used with any array of data (those objects implementing the *Array* class (that is, byte[], short[], int[] and so on).

Essentially the code above tell to the GC: take the address of *pixels*, and don't move it untill I call Free() on the memory handle.

Usin the fixed statement is another option, but requires an unsafe P/Invoke declaration and it's a little more verbose to use it in the code (for each call you have to define an *unsafe* and *fixed* statements).

Comment: The problem above can be solved by adding the line GL.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); Does some one know why else the texture would be white ? It went back to white in my project and I set all 4 texparameter.